# Double curly brace notation not being compiled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following "Angular HTML"

```
<div class="radio input-l" ng-repeat="carPark in initialPlace.carParks" ng-show="!carPark.isBlueBadgeCarpark || isBlueBadge">
    <input type="radio" name="payment"  ng-change="updateParkingSpaces(carPark, initialPlace)" ng-model="initialPlace.selectedCarpark" value="{{carPark.carparkID}}" id="carpark-{{carPark.carparkID}}">
    <label for="carpark-{{carPark.carparkID}}">
        £{{carPark.cost}} - {{carPark.carparkName}}
    </label>
</div>
```

which renders and works fine in FireFox/Chrome/Safari/[insert another decent browser here]

This is a plunker of what I am trying to do, I can't get plunker (even the root site) working on my MSIE so I have no idea if it behaves correctly, but it really is as simple as this

But in MSIE 7/8 I still seem to get "{{carPark.cost}}" rather than the value

everything else seems to work fine, except the {{ ... }} notations

MSIE 7 Error:
 [$sce:iequirks] Strict Contextual Escaping does not support Internet Explorer version < 9 in quirks mode.  You can fix this by adding the text  to the top of your HTML document.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce for more information.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$sce/iequirks

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: in good ole fashion ie dev tools way it simply says "[object Error]undefined" with no more information (no line number, cant click on it, etc, etc)

Comment: oh and "break on error" is selected and it doesnt break

Comment: I have just tried to add JSON2 to the build as this is suggested to be the issue (didnt realise i was using JSON but oh well) and the error i get is now included above

Comment: good question, it appears to of vanished: http://plnkr.co/edit/su31oOcDf3RaHJIEwv5f?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I just had to add a reference to JSON3.js. For some reason JSON2.js wouldn't work but JSON3 worked fine, I used cdnjs.com for the cdn